# Set user password after creating user

Tags: user-registration, wp-login-form

I have the following code:

```
function create_account(){
    //You may need some data validation here
    $fname = ( isset($_POST['billing_first_name']) ? $_POST['billing_first_name'] : '' );
    $lname = ( isset($_POST['billing_last_name']) ? $_POST['billing_last_name'] : '' );

    $email = ( isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '' );
    $pass = ( isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '' );

    $phone = ( isset($_POST['billing_phone']) ? $_POST['billing_phone'] : '' );

    if ( !fname_exists( $fname ) && !lname_exist( $lname ) && !email_exists( $email ) && !pass_exist( $pass ) && !phone_exist( $phone ) ) {

        $user_id = wp_create_user( $fname, $lname, $email, $pass, $phone );

        if( !is_wp_error($user_id) ) {
           //user has been created
           $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
           $user->set_role( 'customer' );
           //Redirect
           wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, false, is_ssl() );
           wp_redirect( '/checkout' );

           exit;
       } else {
           //echo 'Register failed';
       }
    }

}
add_action('init','create_account');
```

This is working properly except login. I can't log in. The password is wrong, but after the password is changed in the database or wp-admin, then login is working properly. So I am sure my code is not storing the password in the database.

Here is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="pwsuf-user-form pwsuf-signup-form">
    <div class="pwsuf-result-error"></div>

    <div class="pwsuf-form-row form-row validate-required">
        <input type="text" name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" class="pwsuf-input input-text" placeholder="First name" value="" required=""><span class="pwsuf-error">Please enter First name</span></div>
    <div class="pwsuf-form-row form-row validate-required">
        <input type="text" name="billing_last_name" id="billing_last_name" class="pwsuf-input input-text" placeholder="Last name" value="" required=""><span class="pwsuf-error">Please enter Last name</span></div>
    <div class="pwsuf-form-row form-row validate-required">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="pwsuf-input input-text" placeholder="Email" value="" required=""><span class="pwsuf-error">Please enter Email</span></div>
    <div class="pwsuf-form-row form-row ">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="pwsuf-input input-text" placeholder="Password" value="" required=""><span class="pwsuf-error">Please enter Password</span></div>
    <div class="pwsuf-form-row form-row validate-required">
        <input type="tel" name="billing_phone" id="billing_phone" class="pwsuf-input input-text" placeholder="Phone" value="" required=""><span class="pwsuf-error">Please enter Phone</span></div>
    <div class="pwsuf-form-row pwsuf-row-btn checkout-buttons-wrap">
        <span data-link="step-2" data-page="step-1" class="button alt wc-forward fleft no-validate">Continue as Guest</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="wp-submit-type" value="register">
        <input type="submit" name="signup-submit" class="pwsuf-button pwsuf-singup btn checkout-button" value="Create account">
        <div class="loader-fountain"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkout-buttons-wrap">
        <span class="pwsuf-link pwsuf-link_reg">Already have account</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you don't put the good arguments for [wp_create_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user)

Comment: wp_generate_password not very good idea, because i need got user password from my form -user determines the password for himself

Comment: @Lerry that's not what Kaperto is talking about, you aren't calling the function with the correct parameters, `wp_create_user` does not accept a first and last name as the first and second parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kaperto is right, your call looks like this:

```php
$user_id = wp_create_user( $fname, $lname, $email, $pass, $phone );
```

But those are not the correct parameters for `wp_create_user`:

```php
wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
```

What you're creating is a user whose username is the first name, and their password is their last name.

Comment: oh Sir, many thanks, but if i need also $fname, $lname, $phone  how better i can use this?

Comment: That's a very good question, eitherway you need to pass a username as the first parameter, I suggest you manufacture one using the first and last names. If you want to set the first/last name fields of that user though,  that's a good question, and one you should ask on the site as a separate question _"Given a user ID that has just been created, how do I set the first and last name of that user?"_. You're much more likely to get a good answer that way than a quick comment can ever manage